# Loading PNG by default, upgrading to SVG if capable

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I want to load a png icon by default to support old devices that cannot process JS reliably. However if you're viewing on a modern browser or device you should see the svg version of the icon. I'm running the following code in the head.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var i, elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var filetype = elements[i].getAttribute('src').split("."),
        extention = filetype.pop();

    if(extention.toLowerCase() == 'png'){
      var hasSVGAttribute = elements[i].getAttribute('data-svg-enhance');

        if (hasSVGAttribute !== null) {
          elements[i].src = hasSVGAttribute;
          elements[i].removeAttribute('data-svg-enhance');
        } else {
          elements[i].src = filetype.join('.')+'.svg';
        }
     }

  };
}
```

This is what my modified image tag looks like:

```
<img src="img/png/home.png" data-svg-enhance="img/svg/home.svg" alt="Home">
```

All is good on low end devices. It will load the png and won't bother with the svg at all. The problem is on top end devices like an iPhone that do support all the tech. The script works, but it loads the png by default, so I'm now loading both the png AND the svg which is super inefficient.

I can't figure out how to select one or the other.

Comment: You need to detect support for SVG images **before** setting the `src`. Based on whether the current browser supports it, you set the `src` appropriately.

Comment: Yes indeed, but how would one detect that without JS. There has to be a src set by default so old devices that don't support JS still show the appropriate png image.

Comment: Who said you need to detect it without JS? In JS, either add the image dynamically with the specific `src`, or find the element (like by `id` or `class`) and set its `src` (and maybe show it, being hidden by default)

Answer (score 0):

It look like this is the best solution, although it isn't 100% valid markup.

```
      <svg width="36" height="36">
        <image xlink:href="img/svg/home.home.svg" src="img/png/home.home.png" width="36" height="36" alt="Shoprite Specials" />                
      </svg>
```

This falls back to a png on old devices and immediately loads the svg on capable devices. ie 9 - 11 has problems with it though.

More: http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/